# Play! Framework 2.0 - Looping through a map in a scala template?

Tags: templates, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a map representing a table of contents, it contains `Chapter` keys and `List[Section]` values. Right now I am trying to loop through this in my template like this:

```
<dl>
@table_of_contents.foreach((e) => {
    <dt>
        @e._1.title
    </dt>
        for(section <- e._2){
        <dd>
            @section.title
        </dd>
        }
})
</dl>
```

I currently get no output in the `<dl>` however.

I added a `println(table_of_contents)` statement to the top of the template to ensure that the map did in fact have data and it printed:

`{models.Chapter@1=BeanList size[4] hasMoreRows[false] list[models.Section@1, models.Section@2, models.Section@3, models.Section@4], models.Chapter@2=BeanList size[0] hasMoreRows[false] list[]}`

perhaps I need to use an imperative style?

UPDATE:

Still working on this... got this variation to compile but no output.

```
<dl>
@table_of_contents.foreach{case(a, b) => {
    <dt>
        @a.title
    </dt>
        @displaySections(b)
}}
</dl>

...

@displaySections(sections: List[Section]) = {
  @for(a_section <- sections) {
        <dd>@a_section.title</li>
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't much experience of Play, but is it because the return type of `foreach` is `Unit`? Have you tried using `map` instead?

Comment: @Gareth I think that you where right, I changed the loop to use `for()` syntax instead of calling the `foreach()` method and it worked

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**tl;dr**

The answers given so far (by [@wbarksdale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546427/wbarksdale), [@PlexQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477399/plexq) and [@Daniel C. Sobral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral) in a comment) are good enough to target the problem described here.

But they're missing a real explanation about why the initial code, using `foreach`, doesn't work.

It cannot work because `foreach` returns `Unit`.

**Play concepts**

Let me give a quick note/recall about how templates work.

The Scala templating system provided by default in Play Framework 2 is indeed built upon FP concepts and thus it uses a lot of immutable structures and so forth.

Moreover, such Scala template (let's say `myTemplate.scala.html`) will be compiled into a regular Scala `object` which has an `apply` method called. This latter function enables us to *call* the object as a function with some parameters (those declared in the first line of the template).

This `object` is also relying on a construction like [`BaseScalaTemplate`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/templates/src/main/scala/play/api/templates/ScalaTemplate.scala) which is built with an output formatter (Html). This formatter will be able to take stuff (like a `String`, `Unit` , `Seq[Int]`, `Map[A,B]`, ...) and render it into HTML code.

Formatting will take place while using the `_display_` method of `BaseScalaTemplate`, which returns an instance of the *formatted output*. This display method will be called in the *compiled* code of the `.scala.html` file in the object's `apply` method's body.

So the body could end like that:

```
def apply/*1.2*/(testMap:scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, Int]):play.api.templates.Html = 
  _display_ {
    Seq[Any](
      _display_(
        Seq[Any](
          /*3.2*/testMap/*3.9*/.map/*3.13*/ { e =>
            _display_(Seq[Any](_display_(Seq[Any](/*5.3*/e))))
          }
        )
      )
    )
  }
```

See? The `_display_` calls aren't mutating anything but they are composed in such a way that apply itself will return an instance of the formatted code (`Html`)!

That gives us the clue...

**yeah blah blah... now why?**

After those lightnings given about the Play internals, we can now tackle the real question: why the hell is the ideomatic Scala code provided in the question post isn't working... read, doesn't output anything at all.

It's pretty simple, when using `foreach` on a `Map`, you're indeed *looping* over the items and *adapting* them to Html. But these computation won't be usable by the templating system because they are enclosed in the `foreach`'s loop. That is `foreach` has to be used when side-effects are required for each item in the sequence... And return `Unit` when it's done.

Since, the templating system will try to `_display_` the result of `foreach` on the given `Map` it will simply render/format `Unit` and thus an empty `String`!

To conclude, just use `map` which will return a new sequence holding the *adapted* items, the `Html` instance.

**Hmmm and what about the `for`?**

Yeah, you're right... Based on what has been said, why are the answers that proposed to used a `for` loop working, since without yielding a value, a `for` is equivalent to `foreach`!? (Introducing `yield` will end in a `map`-like behavior)

The answer is in the code... The Template compiler will prepend the `yield` keyword to the `for`'s body -- check this out [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/templates-compiler/src/main/scala/play/templates/ScalaTemplateCompiler.scala#L383). :-D

*Et voilà*, it works too, since the generated stuffs in the `for`'s body will be attached to a returned sequence after it has finished.

Comment: The link in this answer is 404 and I'm still so confused as to use For, Foreach or Map in Play framework, it's a horror to wrap loops in templates to spit out the structure I need.

Answer (score 19):

The solution I came up with looked like this. Basically it just avoids using functional programming which I am ok with for the time being, but I would still really like to see a working solution using scala functional style.

```
<dl>
@for((key, value) <- table_of_contents) {
    <dt>
        @key.getTitle
    </dt>
        @displaySections(value)
}
</dl>

@displaySections(sections: List[Section]) = {
  @for(a_section <- sections) {
        <dd>@a_section.getTitle</li>
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `@table_of_contents.map { case (key, value) =>`.

Comment: I don't recall seeing it dissembled like that, with a partial function, that's nifty.  I continue to be amazed at what Scala can do.

Answer (score 8):

Play in Scala uses the functional nature of Scala very well.  Change this to a map that returns the elements, and it should work.

```
<dl>
@table_of_contents.map( case(k,v) => {
    <dt>
        @k.title
    </dt>
    @v.map { section =>
        <dd>
            @section.title
        </dd>
    }
})
</dl>
```

As per suggestion above, with the case, it turns it into a partial function that does what we want rather nicely!

Comment: Thanks @PlexQ, I am getting an error `expected start of definition` on the line `@e._2.map { section =>` . I haven't really bumped into Scala too much, but I have started learning it since posting this, and am amazed by how expressive it is. really cool stuff!

Comment: I got illegal start of expression on `case(k, v)` sorry :( haha

Comment: try moving the brace to before the case keyword, I actually tested this and it was working, so I know what is here is pretty damn close.  Obviously it was somewhat adapted for your particular scenario

Comment: I've edited the solution to something I was able to get working myself.

Comment: @wbarksdale: I just got this too, fixed by replacing the parentheses with curly braces.